# How to store data on device while installing app

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working on react-native version 0.56.0. I am trying to store data on device while app installation. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

1. If you want to store a lot of data, you can use a database SQLite.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

2. If you want to store some data you can use AsyncStorage, it is very helpful and easy to use. (In your version it is ok, but now it is deprecated, you need to use community repository)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/asyncstorage

3. You can store your redux store in your app using a component called redux-persist. It if very helpfull to store the information that your application has and is optimized with AsyncStorage.

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist